# Number of prime ideal of $ \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$ above $(2)$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, ramification

I want to prove number of prime ideal of $ \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$ above $(2)$ is 1.

My try: From ramification theory, (number of prime ideal above $(2)$)=[$\Bbb{Q}[ \sqrt{-5}:\Bbb{Q}]/$(order of decomposition group at $(2)$). Now, decomposition group is isom to $Gal(\Bbb{Q}_2(\sqrt{-5})/\Bbb{Q}_2)$ which is order $2$, so there is only one prime above $(2)$.

But I think this is overkill, could you tell me what is the standard way to prove this kind of statement ?

Comment: The polynomial $x^2+5$ factors as a square modulo $2$, so the prime $(2)$ factors as the square of a prime, so only one prime.

Comment: What is your definition of 'prime above $(2)$ ' here ?

Comment: Prime in the ring of integers that contains $(2)$. I'm using the theorem that says that if the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then the factorization of $(q)$ into primes "looks like" the factorization of $p(x)$ modulo $q$.

Comment: Note that $2$ must ramify, as it is not prime (it divides $(1+\sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})$ but does not divide either factor), and if $2$ divides a product of two squares, then it divides one of the squares.

Comment: Saying that $(x+1)^2+5$ is Eisenstein at $2$ is not overkill, and it is very close to appealing to the $2$-adics.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you know that for a number field $K$ with number ring $\mathcal{O}_K$, $[K : \mathbb{Q}] = n$, and $p$ a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, the sum of the products of the ramification and inertial degrees of the primes $P_1, \dots, P_r$ of $\mathcal{O}_K$ lying over $p$ is equal to $n$, i.e., $\sum_{i = 1}^r e_if_i = n$. In your case, $n = 2$, so if $p$ ramifies in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ you know it's totally ramified. Thus, it suffices to use the discriminant criterion, which says that $p$ ramifies in a number ring $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if it divides the discriminant of $\mathcal{O}_K$.

Since $-5 \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$, the discriminant of your number ring is $-20$. Clearly, $2 \mid -20$, so $2$ is ramified in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.